# Adding Java.Swing Timer to Synchronize US for player and AI

Tags: java, swing, timer, artificial-intelligence

I am making an AI to play against a human. The game is set up as an array of buttons and the user and AI take turns switching off making changes to the board (the icon on the button changes). The user obviously has to click on a button and an action listener picks it up and calls the appropriate methods. Then it calls the AI and the AI calls methods to get it's moves taken care of.

The issue is that after the user makes his/her move, the AI makes its move so fast that we don't see the user's move (if the AI's move changed the same button as the user). Thread.sleep doesn't work because it also puts the GUI thread to sleep, but the current code I have to get the timer working doesn't do anything (in the last else of the method)! What should I be doing?

```
//When a button is clicked, this method is called
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{   
    String btName = e.getActionCommand(); //finds out the name of the button that was clicked
    if (btName == "HOW TO PLAY") //if the button "How to Play" is clicked, it does the following
    {
        howTo.txtPnl(); //(method found below)
    }
    else if(who%2 == 0){//it is the AI's turn
        return;         
    }
    else{
        //gets the row and column of the button clicked if it is part of the game grid
        int col = 0;
        int row = 0;

        String s = "";
        String c = "";
        JButton btn = (JButton) e.getSource();
        s += btn.getClientProperty("rval");
        row = Integer.parseInt(s);
        s = "";
        s += btn.getClientProperty("cval");
        col = Integer.parseInt(s);
        c += btn.getClientProperty("clr");

        if(c.equals("") || c.equals("R"))
        {
            changeSquareAndRipple("R", row, col);//set the icons of the board
            countField.setText("BLUE PLAYER'S TURN           # OF BLUE ATOMS: " + countBlue() + "            # OF RED ATOMS: " + countRed()); //updates gameboard         

            who++;
            if(disableBoardOnSuccess()){//end of game
                return;
            }
            else{//allow GUI to make changes before going to AI
                Timer timer = new Timer(1000, this);
                timer.start(); 

                actionAI();  
            }                                     
        }   
    }        
}
```

Comment: A side recommendation, don't do this: `if (btName == "HOW TO PLAY")`. Understand that `==` and `!=` checks for *reference* equality, which is not what you want. You want functional equality which the `equals(...)` and `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` will handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't how timers work. Read the [Swing documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html). It's pretty clear. You need to start the timer where you currently are, then invoke the AI in the timer's handler, which will be called later.  The else block will now look something like:

```
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    actionAI();
  }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(delay, taskPerformer)
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```